# How to create multi-column indices DuckDB/SQLite?

Tags: r, sqlite, duckdb

I have a DuckDB with columns of data which I would like to query using multiple columns. I'm in R but I'm not sure how to create a multicolumn index (or even a single column index). Can anyone suggest a reference please? I've added SQLite as a tag because I gather that the commands could be the same.

**Edit:**
Based on kukuk1de's recommendation I'm trying the following

```
require(DBI)
require(duckdb)

DBI::dbExecute(con,statement = "CREATE INDEX multi_idx ON  (percent prevalence fresh_flow maskProp dropExhale)")
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  duckdb_prepare_R: Failed to prepare query CREATE INDEX multi_idx ON  (percent prevalence fresh_flow maskProp dropExhale)
Error: Parser Error: syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: CREATE INDEX multi_idx ON  (percent prevalence fresh_flow maskProp...
```

Comment: Suspecting you are using the R package `duckdb` you can connect to your DB and send an CREATE INDEX statement via `dbExecute`. See basic examples here https://duckdb.org/docs/api/r

For indexes go here https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/indexes

Comment: Ahhh thank you. I didn't realise what dbExecute was for. I was looking at the r API section and wasn't thinking outside the box. If you could write it as an answer with an example please, I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
library("DBI")

con = dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), dbdir=":memory:", read_only=FALSE)

dbExecute(con, "CREATE TABLE items(item VARCHAR, value DECIMAL(10,2), count INTEGER)")
dbExecute(con, "INSERT INTO items VALUES ('jeans', 20.0, 1), ('hammer', 42.2, 2)")

dbExecute(con, "CREATE INDEX itemcount_idx ON items (item, count);")
```

Running the last command again will tell you the index already exists.

```
dbExecute(con, "CREATE INDEX itemcount_idx ON items (item, count);")
Error in duckdb_execute(res) : duckdb_execute_R: Failed to run query
Error: Catalog Error: Index with name "itemcount_idx" already exists!
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that has worked! It's not changed the GB weight of the DB file so how can I tell that it is working during querying?

Comment: Good question. dbGetQuery(con, "PRAGMA show_tables;") shows the index visible as a separate table. These are details I'm not familiar with for duckdb. Probably you can get support on this on duckdb.org or the github page for duckdb.